# Elasticsearch Nest add multiple range queries

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a `dynamic` search descriptor builder. One of the steps is to go through a list of range filters and add that to the search descriptor.
However any range query I add overwrites the previous range query.
How can I append the range query to the list of range queries already added

```
public SearchDescriptor<dynamic> FilterSearch(SearchDescriptor<dynamic> searchDescriptor, List<FilterField> filters)
{
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        searchDescriptor = AddFilterToSearch(searchDescriptor, filter);
    }

    return searchDescriptor;
}

private static SearchDescriptor<dynamic> AddFilterToSearch(SearchDescriptor<dynamic> searchDescriptor, FilterField filter)
{
    var range = new RangeQuery
    {
        Field = filter.Field
    };
    var term = new TermQuery
    {
        Field = filter.Field
    };

    string rangeValue = filter.Value == null ? null : JsonConvert.ToString(filter.Value);

        // trim the quotes that JsonConvert wraps around the value for some reason
    if (rangeValue != null && rangeValue.StartsWith("\"") && rangeValue.EndsWith("\""))
        rangeValue = rangeValue.Substring(1, rangeValue.Length - 2);

    switch (filter.Operator)
    {
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.LowerThan:
            range.LowerThan = rangeValue;
            break;
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.LowerThanOrEqualTo:
            range.LowerThanOrEqualTo = rangeValue;
            break;
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.Equals:
            if (filter.Value != null && filter.Value is string)
                filter.Value = filter.Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
            term.Value = filter.Value;
            break;
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.GreaterThan:
            range.GreaterThan = rangeValue;
            break;
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            range.GreaterThanOrEqualTo = rangeValue;
            break;
    }

    switch (filter.Operator)
    {
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.LowerThan:
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.LowerThanOrEqualTo:
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.GreaterThan:
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            searchDescriptor = searchDescriptor.Query(range);
            break;
        case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.Equals:
            searchDescriptor = searchDescriptor.Query(term);
            break;
    }

    return searchDescriptor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you are using NEST i think that you should use QueryContainer.

```
var result = _Instance.Search<Record>(s => s
              .Index("indexName")
              .Type("type")
              .Query(q =>
              {
                QueryContainer query = null;
                QueryContainer filter1 = null;
                QueryContainer filter2 = null;
                QueryContainer filter3 = null;

                query = q.QueryString(qs=>qs.OnFields(f => f.RecordValue).Query(term));

                filter1 = q.Filter(ff => ff.Range(n => n.OnField(f => f.minAge).Lower(20));
                filter2 = q.Filter(ff => ff.Range(n => n.OnField(f => f.minAge).Greater(20)); 
                filter3 = q.Filter(ff => ff.Range(n => n.OnField(f => f.maxAge).Lower(60));                   

                //You can put some conditions in here so you will
                switch (filter.Operator)
                {
                    case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.LowerThan:
                        return query && filter1;
                        break;
                    case Enums.ComparrisonOperator.GreaterThan:
                        return query && filter2;
                        break;
                }
              })
              .Take(10)
              );
```

Or something like that.... hope it helps ! Of course ... this is for Elasticsearch < 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can add it with querycontainer as shown below:

```
var queryContainers = new List<QueryContainer>();            
var descriptor = new QueryContainerDescriptor<ProcedureServiceRequest>();
queryContainers.Add(descriptor.DateRange(r => r.Field(f => f.Patient.Birthdate).GreaterThanOrEquals(startDate).LessThanOrEquals(endDate)));            
var queryContainer = new QueryContainerDescriptor<ProcedureServiceRequest>().Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Specialty).Query("Ortho1"));
queryContainers.Add(queryContainer);
var queryContainer2 = new QueryContainerDescriptor<ProcedureServiceRequest>().Match(m => m.Field(f => f.PerformingPhysician.Id).Query("Practitioner2"));            
queryContainers.Add(queryContainer2);


var filterQuery = new BoolQuery
{
    Filter = queryContainers
};


var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<ProcedureServiceRequest>(s => s // Define the search query
                        .Index(indexName).Take(10000)
                        .Query(q => q
                         .Bool(b => b
                            .Filter(filterQuery

                            )
                            .Must(m => m
                        .QueryString(qs => qs
                        
                        .Fields(fs => fs.Field("*"))
                        .Query(query))))).Sort(srt => srt.Field(f=> {
                            f.Order(Nest.SortOrder.Ascending);

                            switch (sortfield)
                            {
                                case "Birthdate":
                                    f.Field(ff => ff.Patient.Birthdate);
                                    break;
                               
                                default:
                                    f.Field(ff => ff.Start);
                                    f.Descending();
                                    break;
                            }

                            return f;
                        })));          
return searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?